# Implementing Stackless Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-stackless, greenlets

I really admire the functionality of Stackless Python, and I've been looking around for a way to emulate its syntax while still using the standard Python 3 interpreter. [An article by Alex J. Champandard in a gamedev blog](http://aigamedev.com/open/article/round-robin-multi-tasking/) made it look as though the greenlet library could provide this functionality. I slightly modified his code, but the best makeshift tasklet wrapper I could come up with was a class holding a greenlet inside a variable, as such:

```
class tasklet(): 
        def __init__(self,function=None,*variables):
                global _scheduled
                self.greenlet = greenlet.greenlet(function,None)
                self.functioncall = function # Redundant backup
                self.variables = variables
                _scheduled.append(self)
                self.blocked = False
```

The function then emulates Stackless' scheduling by passing the variables to the greenlet when calling its `switch()` method.

So far this appears to work, but I'd like to be able to call the tasklets in original Stackless syntax, e.g. `tasklet(function)(*args)`, as opposed to the current syntax of `tasklet(function,*args)`. I'm not sure where to look in the documentation to find out how to accomplish this. Is this even possible, or is it part of Stackless' changes to the interpreter?

Comment: There are implementations of the Stackless API based on greenlet already. I do not provide links as I do not have reputation, and when I try and share research, I get errors rejecting posts. It's a lot less wasted time for me to say just google it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article from 2010-01-08](http://ptspts.blogspot.nl/2010/01/emulating-stackless-python-using.html) (with fixed links):

> [Stackless Python](http://www.stackless.com/) is an extended version of the Python language (and
>   its CPython reference implementation). New features include
>   lightweight coroutines (called tasklets), communication primitives
>   using message passing (called channels), manual and/or automatic
>   coroutine scheduling, not using the C stack Python function calls, and
>   serialization of coroutines (for reloading in another process).
>   Stackless Python could not be implemented as a Python extension module
>   – the core of the CPython compiler and interpreter had to be patched.
>
> [greenlet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet) is an extension module to CPython providing coroutines and
>   low-level (explicit) scheduling. The most important advantage of
>   greenlet over Stackless Python is that greenlet could be implemented
>   as a Python extension module, so the whole Python interpreter doesn't
>   have to be recompiled in order to use greenlet. Disadvantages of
>   greenlet include speed (Stackless Python can be 10%, 35% or 900%
>   faster, depending on the workflow); possible memory leaks if
>   coroutines have references to each other; and that the provided
>   functionality is low-level (i.e. only manual coroutine scheduling, no
>   message passing provided).
>
> greenstackless, the Python module I've recently developed, provides
>   most of the (high-level) Stackless Python API using greenlet, so it
>   eliminates the disadvantage of greenlet that it is low-level. See the
>   [source code](https://code.google.com/p/syncless/source/browse/trunk/syncless/greenstackless.py) and [some tests](https://code.google.com/p/syncless/source/browse/trunk/test/stackless_test.py) (the latter with tricky corner cases).
>   Please note that although greenstackless is optimized a bit, it can be
>   much slower than Stackless Python, and it also doesn't fix the memory
>   leaks. Using greenstackless is thus not recommended in production
>   environments; but it can be used as a temporary, drop-in replacement
>   for Stackless Python if replacing the Python interpreter is not
>   feasible.
>
> Some other software that emulates Stackless using greenlet:
>
> [Concurrence](https://github.com/concurrence/concurrence/blob/master/lib/concurrence/_stackless.py): doesn't support stackless.main, tasklet.next,
>   tasklet.prev, tasklet.insert, tasklet.remove,
>   stackless.schedule_remove, doesn't send exceptions properly. (Because
>   of these features missing, it doesn't pass the unit test above.)
>
> [PyPy](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/67067c56ae1a8f3c07007759c55b458a7ed88836/lib_pypy/stackless.py?at=default): doesn't support stackless.main, tasklet.next, tasklet.prev,
>   doesn't pass the unit test above.